# Bug em Option List com Loaders

Tags: lawtex

Estou tentando fazer uma option list no loaders de uma Struct. O código sobe, mas na hora de executar aparece o Bug abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um template de exemplo para tentar isolar o erro e identificar o problema:

```
        +<a> : Struct {
            name = "Exemplo A"
            fields {
                +[booleanA] : Boolean {
                    name = "Sim ou Não"
                    request = "Sim ou Não"
                }
            }
        },
        +<b> : Struct {
            name = "Exemplo B"
            fields {
                +[listaA] : List ("Item A", "Item B", "Item C", "Item D") {
                    name = "Selecione o item da lista"
                    request = "Selecione o item da lista"
                    atomic = false
                }
            }
            loaders {
                if([a.booleanA] == true) {
                    [listaA].options = {"Item A", "Item B"}
                } else {
                    [listaA].options = {"Item C", "Item D"}
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse bug acontece porque o `loaders` somente processa objetos dentro da `struct` na qual ele está inserido. No exemplo, ele se encontra dentro da `struct` `<b>`, não conseguindo operar com objetos da `struct` `<a>`. Para corrigir isso, é necessário juntar as `structs` `<a>` e `<b>` do exemplo. Vou demonstrar no código abaixo:

```
    +<a> : Struct {
        name = "Exemplo A"
        fields {
            +[booleanA] : Boolean {
                name = "Sim ou Não"
                request = "Sim ou Não"
            },
            +[listaA] : List ("Item A", "Item B", "Item C", "Item D") {
                name = "Selecione o item da lista"
                request = "Selecione o item da lista"
                atomic = false
            }
        }
        loaders {
            if([booleanA] == true) {
                [listaA].options = {"Item A", "Item B"}
            } else {
                [listaA].options = {"Item C", "Item D"}
            }
        }
    }
```

Se não desejar juntar as estruturas, vai ser necessário fazer a operação em um `branch` de lógica, e não pelo `loaders`. Considerando que as estruturas sejam as do exemplo sem o loaders, o `branch` de `lógica` ficaria conforme o código abaixo:

```
    branch[BRC_Logica] {
        operations {
            if([a.booleanA] == true) {
                [b.listaA].options = {"Item A", "Item B"}
            } else {
                [b.listaA].options = {"Item C", "Item D"}
            }
        }
    }
```